# Rooted Moto E won't start Wi-Fi

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

i did a hard reset on my rooted Moto E android device since the Wi-fi was not somehow turning on. Now it has rebooted, and after entering the preferred language, its got stuck on the second step : Select Wi-Fi, and shows the text "turning Wi-Fi on...". ( the same problem for which I did a hard reset in the first place). Why is the reboot stuck at this point and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 0):

Can u post a pic of Ur WiFi select screen or give some more information.
Since u have rooted your phone, u can boot into recovery and try to wipe dalvik cache and factory reset.
Hope it solves your WiFi problem if not,then it might be a hardware issue.

Comment: I tried the recovery mode - I chose the option 'wipe data and reboot. But after the reboot, its the same situation. I don't know how I can post an image in this comment

Comment: Since u have rooted,which recovery have u added, if it is Philz or cwm recovery then go to advanced -> wipe dalvik cache. Try installing another rom and see if the problem still persist.

Comment: Its cwm recovery. I wiped the dalvik cache, did a factory reset, and tried installing the one of the latest condor ROMs - however, the message I get is 'installation aborted' because 'could not detect filesystem for /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system. assuming ext4

Comment: cwm recovery,wiped dalvik cache, did factory reset, & tried installing the latest condor ROMs - however, the message I get is "installation aborted' because 'could not detect filesystem for /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system. assuming ext4   mount: failed to mount /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system at /system: No such file or directory  unmount of /system failed; no such volume patching system image unconditionally.... E1001: Failed to update system image. E:unknown command[log] E:Error in /storage/sdcard1/lineage-14.1-20170620-nightly-condor-signed.zip (status 7) Installation aborted"

Comment: see this link.     https://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-e/orig-development/rom-cyanogenmod-14-moto-e-t3460506/page101